# EnableAuthorizationServer is working and is not deprecated

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I was following this [guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) which mentions that the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is deprecated. But when I created a project with the following dependencies, I am not getting the deprecated messages. Is there something I am missing here.

Depedencies - Output from `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ spring-oauth-server ---
[INFO] com.classpath:spring-oauth-server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.5.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.10.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:29.0-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.10.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.16.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.18:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.18:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
```

Spring Dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      ...
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
      ...
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             ...
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In My Root class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer   // this is a protected resource
@EnableAuthorizationServer  //acts as a OAuth2 service
public class SpringOauthServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringOauthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I do not see any Deprecated messages.

Comment: how can we know, you have omitted the spring version, so afaik you could be using a old version of spring.

Comment: I have updated the version of Spring Security OAuth2 -  Spring Security OAuth2 version - 2.3.4.RELEASE

Comment: that doesnt help, you need to include all versions, spring boot, security, etc, and also a mvn dependecy:tree so we know that no version is overriding any other. If you post a pom.xml, dont strip away information. Update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: @Toerktumlare updated the depdendencies in the post

Comment: The deprecation commit is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/6234826671d75632d84c524da1dd8818cee1b4c2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well the correct term is that `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is in `maintenance mode` which basically means deprecated. As in there will be no added features or updates.

The story goes basically as follows.

During Spring 4 i believe there was a single person that maintained the oauth2 part of spring security. When Spring security 5 was launched the team at pivotal decided to do a major overhaul of spring security and the oauth2 parts. So what they did was to drop Authorisation server support, and instead focus on the Resource server support at first.

[Spring announcement of dropping Authorisation server support](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update)

You have pulled in `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2` which in turn har a peer dependency on `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` which in turn pulls in `spring-security-oauth2`.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html5/) Spring clearly states that if you wish to use `spring-security-oauth2` they will help you out, but it is in maintenance mode.

The choice to not support it was made because an authorization server is like owning a product. Spring doesn't maintain their own database, or own Ldap server etc. There are plenty of auth servers out there that can be used, okta, curity, github, fb, google, etc, etc.

But Spring has actually reevaluated that choice and decided to start a community developed [open source authorisation server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server)

So you have 3 choices:

- use the old, that is in maintenance mode
- use a 3rd party vendor, github, fb, google, okta, curity etc.
- try out the new open source authorisation server