# oAuth2 Springboot - add and return more informations in JDBCTokenStore

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, maven, oauth-2.0

I would like to know, if there is a way to add more information in JDBCTokenStore. Let me explain, currently, I am using oauth2 authentication to secure my Spring Boot REST API with JDBCTokenStore.

Here is the AuthorizationServerConfiguration class I am using:

```html
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("isAuthenticated()");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore());
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

When I hit the POST method URL via POSTMAN to get the OAUTH2 token http://localhost:8082/oauth/token I get this json reponse :

```html
{
    "access_token": "e71b98dd-8a53-44f4-9673-fa4c1c54a415",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "ac4e82ec-028a-45a6-8801-fe55fcbdd36e",
    "expires_in": 3042,
    "scope": "READ WRITE"
}
```

Is there a solution to add more information about the user (like email, gender... etc) in my Json JDBCTokenStore?
Apparently, TokenEnhancerChain or JWT is a solution for my problem, except that I cannot integrate them into my code without modifying it too much.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are storing the OIDC user information into a database, as in your code,

```java
    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
```

you are passing in the `dataSource` as an argument. So the Spring framework saves whatever OIDC user information into the `dataSource` you configured here.

It does not matter whether you are using JWT or session ID to authenticate & authorize requests. The key is the `OidcUser` you are working around.

---

## `.getClaims()`

In the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user Interface OidcUser` OIDC user interface, there is a method called `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> getClaims()`. This is the method you invoke to get the customized user info such as `"address": "xxx", "totalApiUsage": 123`.

```
// ...
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser) {
    OidcUser principal = ((OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
    
    // principal.getClaims()
}
```

## `.claim()`

Upon issuing an access token or refresh token, invoke `.claim("xxx",object)` to put a customized key-value pair into your OIDC user information Map, such as `"address": "xxx", "totalApiUsage": 123`.

See also https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/07/25/oidc-primer-part-1

---

Apart from your question, you mentioned that

> currently, I am using oauth2 authentication to secure my Spring Boot REST API with JDBCTokenStore.

It is perfectly fine to work with existing authorization providers such as Facebook, Auth0, Google etc., by using Spring security framework to get the access token from other OAuth2 authorization servers.

However, if you would like have your own OAuth2 authorization server, you should stop using Springboot Authorization server because it is currently in maintenance mode.
See also [EnableAuthorizationServer is working and is not deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590263/enableauthorizationserver-is-working-and-is-not-deprecated)