# Is there any alternative to using @EnableAuthorizationServer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I discovered the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation declared two imports in its declaration namely `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.class` etc, which in turn extends the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I've been trying to implement a custom oauth2 authorization, so I declared a class which has the bean `SecurityFilterChain` and another class annotated with `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. This made my code fail to compile for having both `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `SecurityFilterChain` beans.

Is there any replacement for `@EnableAuthorizationServer`?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer //This annotation declared an import on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in its definition. It seems to conflict with the SecurityFilterChain bean I declared in SecurityConfig class.
public class OAuthServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
//Omitted codes

@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager; //Bean defined somewhere
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);
    }
   @Override 
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
       
       clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("client")
               .secret("secret")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "resfresh_token")
               .scopes("read")
              .redirectUris("http://localhost:9090/home");     
   }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{
//Omitted codes

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.formLogin();
return http.build();
}
}
```

stack trace:

```
14:15:41.474 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@3e24f044

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-07-11 14:15:42.799  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.Authserver.AuthServerApplication   : Starting AuthServerApplication using Java 16.0.2 on DESKTOP-164SH78 with PID 7104 (D:\my-projects\Auth-server2\target\classes started by Chinedu in D:\my-projects\Auth-server2)
2022-07-11 14:15:42.815  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.Authserver.AuthServerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-11 14:15:43.184  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Chinedu\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.3.0.1\jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-api.jar
2022-07-11 14:15:43.184  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Chinedu\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.3.1\jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/txw2-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar,file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/stax-ex-1.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar,file:/C:/Users/Chinedu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
2022-07-11 14:15:43.185  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-07-11 14:15:43.186  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-07-11 14:15:46.143  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=7555e0cb-24d8-3b77-9467-ee10a0e98a84
2022-07-11 14:15:47.446  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-11 14:15:47.474  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-11 14:15:47.475  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-07-11 14:15:47.742  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-11 14:15:47.743  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4556 ms
2022-07-11 14:15:48.951  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1552573e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@17433b43, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7ed12b1b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3a887c8a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@4039479, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2c653d99, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1b1bfdf8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@82e86c4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@57995941, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7fd663bc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@60a16550, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@64d20304, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@af9314c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@65a799cb]
2022-07-11 14:15:49.702  WARN 7104 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
2022-07-11 14:15:49.718  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-11 14:15:49.760  INFO 7104 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-11 14:15:49.831 ERROR 7104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example13i.security.Authserver.AuthServerApplication.main(AuthServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:106) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example13i.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>Auth-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Auth-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My code works if I change the `SecurityConfig` class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.formLogin();
}
}
```

But the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is already deprecated, so I wouldn't want to extend it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EnableAuthorizationServer is working and is not deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590263/enableauthorizationserver-is-working-and-is-not-deprecated)

Comment: @Toerktumlare, not actually. I understand I can delegate authorization to third parties like GitHub or okta, I wanted a custom implementation. But the issue is that my compiler complained I shouldn't have these two beans ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter``` and ```SecurityFilterChain```, instead I should choose just one. When I removed ```SecurityFilterChain``` and allowed my ```SecurityConfig``` class extend ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter```, the code worked. So the issue is having both beans injected in my project and I wouldn't want to extend the deprecated ```WebSecurityFilterChain```

Comment: Eh? `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated not `WebSecurityFilterChain` I suggest you post your full logs with the error.

Comment: Look in the logs, it just says INFO, once again, DEBUG LOGS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246353/discussion-between-chinedu-and-toerktumlare).

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, We are facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this? It would be helpful for us. Thank you in advance